# How to write the cells in rows one under the other in columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list of name, company, phone number, address and e-mail. But each name who works at the same company is in the same cell. Of course, the other informations of those names like phone number, address, etc. are same.

I want to write each name under the other but i have to write its informations side cell of it. Actually, my list is very long and i cannot finish it today. I don' know how to do.

[image: Screenshot describing problem]

Comment: Hi genevive, if you sign up and put your screenshot on [imgur](http://imgur.com/) you can just share a link with us. I think it's the only way we're going to be able to understand your problem.

Comment: Thank you @CLockeWork , I am adding the link now. http://imgur.com/VjqAOUl

Comment: No problem. I take it you've imported this data into Excel; what format was it in originally?

Comment: It was an excel document but i just had a screenshot of the sheet. I edited it in Paint program.

Comment: Sorry, I mean was the data orignally written into Excel like this or did it come from a database?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in front of a Windows computer with Excel right now, but I believe this code should create a new worksheet, and copy the data into the new sheet, splitting the names into separate rows.

```
Sub CopyRowsAndSplitNames
  Dim srcSheet As Excel.Worksheet
  Set srcSheet = Excel.Application.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change this to whatever your worksheet is called

  Dim dstSheet As Excel.Worksheet
  Set dstSheet = Excel.Application.Sheets.Add()

  srcSheet.Rows(1).Copy dstSheet.Rows(1)

  Dim dstRow as Integer
  dstRow = 1

  Dim strName As String
  Dim strNames As String()
  Dim srcRow as Integer
  For srcRow = 2 to srcSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    strNames = Split(srcSheet.Cells(row, 3).Value, ",")
    For Each strName in strNames
      dstRow = dstRow + 1
      srcSheet.Row(srcRow).Copy dstSheet.Row(dstRow)
      dstSheet.Cells(dstRow, 3).value = strName
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  You can start a Query from an Excel Table.

The Split command can be used to split a column based on a delimiter (e.g. Comma).  Then I would use the Unpivot command to turn those multiple columns into multiple rows with a single column.